# Creating an html table using api data

Tags: php, api

I'm requesting sone data from an api source in php, I can get the data an show on page. Its format is like below. I want to put this data in an html table to be readable by users. For example I want to show users from this data only this part "Leicester City 0 Stoke City FC 1". What should I use, can u give me at least an idea where to begin?

{"_links":[{"self":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/fixtures"},{"soccerseason":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354"}],"count":10,"fixtures":[{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/fixtures/137842"},"soccerseason":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354"},"homeTeam":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/338"},"awayTeam":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/70"}},"date":"2015-01-17T15:00:00Z","status":"FINISHED","matchday":22,"homeTeamName":"Leicester City","awayTeamName":"Stoke City FC","result":{"goalsHomeTeam":0,"goalsAwayTeam":1}},{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/fixtures/136834"},"soccerseason":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354"},"homeTeam":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/58"},"awayTeam":{"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/64"}},"date":"2015-01-17T15:00:00Z","status":"FINISHED","matchday":22,"homeTeamName":"Aston Villa

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point the data appears to be json so a good place to start would be to use json_decode so that the data is usable in php.

To get this data in an array within php:

```
$json=json_decode( $data_from_api_call, true );
```

Then loop through the data:

```
foreach( $json as $key ){
    echo $key;
}
```

That should give you a head start on getting what you want